# How to make like and unlike in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony4

I'm designing like and functionality in my project and I'm stuck to display the icon.

User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Image", inversedBy="users")
 */
private $likes;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->likes = new ArrayCollection();
}
 ....
 /**
 * @return Collection|Image[]
 */
public function getLikes(): Collection
{
    return $this->likes;
}

public function addLike(Image $like): self
{
    if (!$this->likes->contains($like)) {
        $this->likes[] = $like;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeLike(Image $like): self
{
    if ($this->likes->contains($like)) {
        $this->likes->removeElement($like);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Image.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="likes")
 */
private $users;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->likes = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
...
/**
 * @return Collection|User[]
 */
public function getUsers(): Collection
{
    return $this->users;
}

public function addUser(User $user): self
{
    if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
        $this->users[] = $user;
        $user->addLike($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeUser(User $user): self
{
    if ($this->users->contains($user)) {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
        $user->removeLike($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Twig

```
          <a href="{{ path('like',{'id':image.id}) }}">
            {% if  user likes the image display this %}  
              <i id="like" class="{{ unlike }} text-danger"></i>&nbsp;{{ image.users.count  }} 

              {% else show this %}
                     <i id="like" class="{{ like }} text-danger"></i>&nbsp;{{ image.users.count  }} 
              {% endif %}
              </a>
```

User repository

```
public function findByLikes($value): ?User
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->leftJoin('l.likes', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.user','e')
        ->addSelect('u','e')
        ->where('l.id = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```

Can anyone help me with the code? I think there is no issue with controller. May be I'm not able to write logic in twig.
So my intentions is to display the icon for the liked and unliked. I have used single icon for both like and unlike. If the user click on like icon that should flip to unlike icon and vice versa.

Comment: assuming the user is connected, test this ... `{% if image.users.contains(app.user) %}`

Comment: Okay, may i misunderstood your logic,  but (i build like, follow, reblog systems in symfony, and so), why your $likes is entity\image, and then, what is image? If, your question is about a like system, why dont show your like entity? (Anyway, will be even simplier your life, if you rename anything about Like to Love (or something), because like is an sql "command" (not command, but english is not my native lang, so, you know), and doctrine cant handle entities and properties what is matched with SQL keywords (you even dont use the like keyword, if your database is some nosql)

Comment: @SilvioQ thank u thank u so much... Your solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the user is connected, your can show the right icon in this way:

```
      <a href="{{ path('like',{'id':image.id}) }}">
      {% if image.users.contains(app.user) %}
          <i id="like" class="{{ unlike }} text-danger"></i>&nbsp;{{ image.users.count }} 
      {% else %}
          <i id="like" class="{{ like }} text-danger"></i>&nbsp;{{ image.users.count }} 
      {% endif %}
       </a>
```